# How do I skip a carrierwave store callback when processing versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, callback, version, carrierwave

I have a callback defined in my `video uploader` class of carrierwave
`after :store, :my_method`
and I have three versions of the files. `original`,`standard`,`low`

`my_method` executes when each version is processed ie, three times, I just need the callback to execute once.

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I have a similar issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know this is a very late response but I was just having the same problem lately so I decided to post how I solved this "problem" since it seems it isn't documented on carrierwave's github page (or I wasn't able to find it anyway).

Ok, regarding the `after :store, :my_method` callback if you place it in the "main body" of your uploader class, then it's going to be executed every single time a file is stored, so in your case I think it even executes not only for your 3 versions but for your original file as well.

Let's say the following code defines your carrierwave uploader:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  after :store, :my_method

  version :original do
    process :resize_to_limit => [1280,960]
  end

  version :standard, from_version: :original do
    process :resize_to_limit => [640,480]
  end

  version :low, from_version: :standard do
    process :resize_to_limit => [320,240]
  end

  protected
    def my_method
      puts self.version_name
    end
end
```

That way, the `after :store` is going to be executed for every file stored, but if you only want it to be executed, let's say, for the `:low` version, all you have to do is to move that line inside your version definition. Like this:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  version :original do
    process :resize_to_limit => [1280,960]
  end

  version :standard, from_version: :original do
    process :resize_to_limit => [640,480]
  end

  version :low, from_version: :standard do
    process :resize_to_limit => [320,240]
    after :store, :my_method
  end

  protected
    def my_method
      puts self.version_name
    end
end
```

I tested it on my code and it works... I know it's been a long time since you posted this question and probably you arrived at the same solution as me. So I decided to answer it for future reference for anyone getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I needed just the same thing, and I found out that the `original` version (which [is called](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-use-callbacks#example) `nil` inside `carrierwave`) is always processed last. I couldn't find out why in the source files, and it feels counter-intuitive when [looking at the code](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb#L18), but simple `puts` with `version_name` reveals that it is so.

You could use this fact for your problem:

```
after :store, :my_method

def my_method(_file = nil)
  return if version_name

  # do something only once, after all versions are stored
end
```

---

I used `carrierwave_backgrounder` gem and its `process_in_background` feature along with [gem's optional `<uploader_name>_processing` column](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder#to-use-process_in_background), which gave me a possibility to use the `after_update` callback on the model like this:

```
# some_model.rb
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  
  after_update do
    if image_processing_changed? && image_processing == false
      # do your stuff e.g. check if the image was actually uploaded to cloud.
      # S3 client from `fog-aws` gem has a handy head_object method to do that.
    end
  end
end
```

I first thought I can't rely on this callback, because I only `process_in_background`, not storing as well, but later I found out that even though the processing takes place in background and [isn't supposed to store in background](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder/blob/v0.4.2/lib/backgrounder/orm/base.rb#L13), it **does include storing** as a part of the `recreate_versions` method, and as the whole process is already happening in background, storing happens in background (though synchronously), too, and it's safe to rely on this callback.

Here's the chain of involved methods calls:
[`process_in_background`](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder/blob/v0.4.2/lib/backgrounder/orm/base.rb#L41), [`ProcessAsset`](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder/blob/v0.4.2/lib/backgrounder/workers/process_asset.rb#L12), [`recreate_versions!`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v1.3.1/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb#L223), [setting `image_processing` flag to false](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder/blob/v0.4.2/lib/backgrounder/workers/process_asset.rb#L13).

`carrierwave 1.3.1` `carrierwave_backgrounder 0.4.2`